# Facebook share button shows thumbnail only after refresh. ZendFramework

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, zend-framework

im using Zend Framework v1, I have implemented the facebook share button on my site. If I click the share button for the first time, the data is fetched (title, description and URL) but not thumbnail. However if I refresh the page, come back and press again the button, the thumbnail is being displayed.

Same thing is when i post a link via fb website - at first time there is no thumbnail but after refreshing fb site and posting link again it is being displayed.

Does anyone know how to make it working?

The meta tags seems to be ok, the fb developer tool shows no errors.

Code in the ZF Controller

```
$this->view->doctype('XHTML1_RDFA');
$this->view->headMeta()->appendProperty('og:title', 'some value');
$this->view->headMeta()->appendProperty('og:type', 'website');
$this->view->headMeta()->appendProperty('og:url', 'http://mydomain/file?name='.$_GET["name"]);
$this->view->headMeta()->appendProperty('og:description', 'some value');
$this->view->headMeta()->appendProperty('og:image', 'http://mydomain/up/'.$_GET["name"]);
```

Comment: I once had a similar issue and it turned out that Facebook's own image caching was the problem. Unfortunately I can't remember what we did to fix this - it was pretty ugly and included the debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). Maybe "?fbrefresh=your-fb-url" will help too (allthough it isn't working with CDNs and the browser-cache wirll hate you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either [trigger a first scrape via API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update) when you publish a new piece of content, or specify the image dimensions via OG meta tags as well.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching:

> There are two ways to avoid this and have images render on the first Like or Share action:
>
> 1. Pre-cache the image with the URL Debugger
> 2. Use `og:image:width` and `og:image:height` Open Graph tags

Comment: Thanks man! **og.image:width** and **og:image:height** works perfectly!

Pre-caching every image in URL Debugger would be impossible in my case. I've got 20k images on server and the number is still growing.